# Orchard Tag Description Page with Blog Posts

Tags: blogs, orchardcms, taxonomy

I have an Orchard Site where I have Pages and Blog Posts both Tagged.  Each Tag has:

- A single associated page
- Multiple associated Blog Posts

I'm basically trying to create a page with a description for each tag with the corresponding blog posts under the description.  Does anyone have advice on the best method to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Taxonomies instead. Taxonomy terms can have a Body part, which basically corresponds to your tag page.

Comment: That worked perfectly.  After Creating a Taxonomy, I had to go into the Content Type Settings and add the Body Part to that specific content type.  Now it's working like a charm!  Thanks!